# Getting an input on the next line of an output

Tags: java, eclipse, input, formatting, output

Basically I am trying to get my code to output the given variables (provided by a user input) to display on a single line below my output.

For example, my code does this:

```
    Enter 3 variables for array X:
    2.1
    3.5
    5.4
```

I want it to do this:

```
    Enter 3 variables for array Y:
    2.1 3.5 5.4
```

Here is my entire code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project4JamesVincent {
   public static void main(String []args){
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter the size of the arrays: ");
     int size = input.nextInt();
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("Enter " + size + " items for array X: ");
     double[] arrayX = createArray(size, input);
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("Enter " + size + " items for array Y: ");
     double[] arrayY = createArray(size, input);
     System.out.print("The distance between x and y is: ");
     double totalDistance = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        totalDistance = totalDistance + Math.abs((arrayX[i]-arrayY[i]));
     }
     double averageDistance = 0;
     averageDistance = (totalDistance/size);
     System.out.printf("%3.2f", averageDistance);
   }    
   public static double[] createArray (int n, Scanner enter){
       double[] tempArray = new double[n];
       for (int i=0; i<tempArray.length; i++){
           tempArray[i] = enter.nextDouble();
       }
       return tempArray;
   }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying you want the user to be able to input the numbers all on the same line? Just separate them with spaces instead of the enter key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your createArray function to this, you can enter numbers either one on each line or all on one line:

```
public static double[] createArray (int n, Scanner enter){
    double[] tempArray = new double[n];
    int pos=0;
    while (enter.hasNext()) {
        tempArray[pos++] = enter.nextDouble();
        if (pos>=n)
            break;
    }
    return tempArray;
}
```